# Chrome Appsアプリを、Chromeの新しいタブに表示することは可能ですか？

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-apps

Chrome Appsアプリとして作られていて高速に動作する「Pocket」を、Google Chromeの新しいタブに表示したいと思って色々と弄ってみたのですが、どうもローカルのURLのようなものが見つかりませんでした。

Chrome Appsでネイティブで動いてるアプリって、HTMLではないのですか？

もしかしてHTML、CSS、JSを含めて全てバイナリに変換してあるということでしょうか？

---

Chrome AppsのPocketアプリ
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pocket/mjcnijlhddpbdemagnpefmlkjdagkogk

Answer (score 2):

基本的には、オフラインで単独起動する Chrome アプリを、ブラウザモードで起動することはできません。別物です。オフラインアプリ（パッケージアプリといいます）は、ブラウザ独自の機能へのアクセスができない前提になっているからです。保存されるデータも、使える権限も異なっています。

Chrome 拡張の本体とデータは、以下の '`User Data`' ディレクトリの下に置かれています。

- Windows 7, 8: `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
- Mac OSX     : `/Users/Home/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`

その下の Extension が拡張本体が入っているディレクトリです。ローカル用、ブラウザ用で構成は
ほとんど同じですが、実行される環境は異なります。例えば、ローカル用に立ち上げられたアプリが、
’`chrome.storage.local`' 経由でデータを保存すると、このディレクトリの 
'`Local Extension Settings`'　が使われることになります。ブラウザのエクステンションであれば
'`databases`' の下にデータを保存しているでしょう。

ただし、簡単な拡張なら、少し手を入れることでブラウザモードで動くエクステンションとして動かすことができるかもしれません。開発される意欲があるのでしたら、 [Webview](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/webview-samples/) サンプルなどから初めてみられてはどうでしょうか。

それとネイティブアプリについてですが、以下のようなファイルで構成されています

- 実行ファイルを呼び出す HTML
- 補助的な Javascript
- 各プラットフォーム向けの実行ファイル　（バイナリファイル）
- アプリケーションの設定　（マニュフェストファイル）

詳しくは、開発者ドキュメントの [Application Structure](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/coding/application-structure) を参考にしてください。
大抵のネイティブアプリは、HTML/Javascript 部分が簡素で、バイナリにほとんどのコードが集中していますので、ネイティブアプリの改変は難しいでしょう。これも、前述の '`Extensions`' ディレクトリに入っていますから一度ご覧になられてみるといいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

オフラインで動作するタイプのChromeアプリは別ウィンドウで開くことしかできません。

Chromeアプリにはローカルに全てのデータを持っていてオフラインで動作するタイプと、通常のWebページと同じくサーバーからデータを取ってきてオンラインで動作するタイプの2種類があり、前者のタイプはタブの中ではなく別ウィンドウとして動作するという仕様になっているようです。

参考：

- https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835455/how-to-open-chrome-apps-as-a-regular-tab-with-its-api

なお前者のオフラインタイプでも、HTML/CSS/JSで作られていることには変わりありません。